# Retrieve all views with identical ID

Tags: android

Suppose I have a `RecyclerView` where the `ViewHolder` binds a layout containing a `View` with a set ID.

**Design:**

```
*RecyclerView
**ViewHolder0
***TextView with ID myTitle
**ViewHolder1
***TextView with ID myTitle
**ViewHolder2
***TextView with ID myTitle
**ViewHolder3
***TextView with ID myTitle
```

If those views are all loaded at the same time, *the screen estate is enough to display all `ViewHolder`s*, how to get hold of all the views with ID myTitle ?

I tried the basic `findViewById(int ResourceID)` however it only gives me the first `TextView` and only when the first one disappears from the screen and probably is removed from the **Tree** I get the second one.

NB: I don't create the View tree myself but have to interact with it.

Comment: Can you tell the purpose of doing such thing? It'll help provide you specific solution to such problem.

Comment: I need to check the text inside those TextView and check there position compared to the top of the screen. If it's easier to achieve, getting the second view would be enough

Comment: One solution (can be helpful) : during your construction initialization of `ViewHolder`, you can setTag to your `TextView` as your `ViewHolder` object. Then get your TextView using method `findViewByTag()` and pass your **viewholder** object there.

Comment: @JeelVankhede that's a great idea, however I don't have control over the construction of such views. These are generated by third party libraries and I need to interact with them

Comment: Do you have any callbacks or such thing upon generation? No, then let me think of something else then.

Comment: How about retrieving the ViewHolders using [`findViewHolderForAdapterPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int)) or [`findViewHolderForLayoutPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(int))? The holder should already have a reference to its own TextView.

Comment: @TheGamer007 I just checked `findViewHolderForLayoutPosition` and I'm not sure I understand well **Return the ViewHolder for the item in the given position of the data set as of the latest layout pass**. If I give it position 1 does it return the layed out viewholder at position 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I made a sample app to compare `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition`, `findViewHolderForLayoutPosition` and the `LayoutManager`'s `getChildAt` functions.

**TL;DR**: You can use `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition` since your views definitely fit in the screen and as long as there aren't many layout changes. The indices would match that of your adapter, so the topmost is `0`.

---

The activity I made had one RecyclerView and a button that when clicked logged the text in the text view with the id `text1` (the layout was `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`). Since all their IDs are also the same, this should match your requirements. The adapter had 20 strings from "Item 0" to "Item 19".

Now note that both `ForLayoutPosition` and `ForAdapterPosition` return `null` if the view is not laid out on screen. The difference between the two as mentioned in the docs for `ForAdapterPosition` is that

> Unlike `findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(int)` this method takes into account any pending adapter changes that may not be reflected to the layout yet. On the other hand, if `notifyDataSetChanged()` has been called but the new layout has not been calculated yet, this method will return null since the new positions of views are unknown until the layout is re-calculated.

So the return of the two is different only if there has been a change in item order. It could have been a swap, a removal or an addition. Anything requiring a layout change would cause the two to diverge, until that layout change happens. After that they return the same value again.

On the other hand, the `LayoutManager` is not aware of the Adapter. So it's positions are purely based on the layout.

To demonstrate via example, say Items 6 to 16 are visible on my screen as below. The boxes are the layout bounds, which I set to be visible.

(Note that in this case the 17th view has not been loaded, but it may be loaded in the layout while Item 6 is partially visible, since it could be scrolled up)

[image: Screenshot of RecylerView]

In the button's `onClick` I log the values for ALL indices `0`-`19` in a for loop (ignore how the button text says "first item"). The result for both `ForAdapterPosition` and `ForLayoutPosition` is that indices `0` to `5` and `17` to `19` which are off-screen return `null`, while `6` to `16` return the actual ViewHolder objects. From those, you could either cast to your custom ViewHolder class and get the View required, or do `holder.itemView.findViewById()`.

Meanwhile, `LayoutManager.getChildAt` returns a `View` as opposed to a `ViewHolder`. It considers `getChildAt(0)` to be the first item on the screen, i.e. `"Item 6"` and `"Item 16"` maps to `getChildAt(10)`. For indices `11` to `19`, it returns `null`.

So while both manage to get the 11 visible views on the screen, I feel it is better to go with `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition` since it would match the positions of items in your adapter in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect each view from the holders and use the `findViewById(R.id.myTitle)` on each of them, like that you will obtain each of the textViews belonging to each of the views inside the recycler.

```
val allTextViews = recyclerView.children
     .mapNotNull { it.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myTitle) }
     .toList()
```